# CSS Float not working correctly

Tags: html, css

Please go through [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zm11awhq/). Here I am presenting the information TV seasons in the form of lists. I am managing these lists to appear next-each-other through setting FLOAT left/right. Some-how few of the lists are not appearing properly.

Any assistance is appreciated.

You can check [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zm11awhq/)

Comment: How many seasons you want per row? Respectively, how many columns you want?

Comment: it depends on how many seasons a show has my website is fully automated it auto adds whenever new season comes and episodes and users add links, Im using float left and right its shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: And why are you alternating `float: left;` and `float: right;`? I really don't get what your desired layout is supposed to look like.

Comment: do you have answer for it ? or not

Comment: Nobody will have an answer as long as your requirements are about as unclear as your question.

Comment: i gave you a fiddle which has everything as i said above i used to float even numbers right and odd numbers left but there is a issue in season four it cant float correctly right.

Comment: Yet it is still unclear which layout your want to achieve. Instead of answering the questions I gave to help you, you insist that your question is fully sufficient the way it is. Good luck then!

Comment: bro what is wrong with you even a blind person can see the issue in fiddle. season 4

Comment: So clearly visibly true now: "even a blind person can see the issue". *But that issue is not in the code.*

Comment: thats why im here i also cant figure it out because there is no issue in code but i thing some where it needs clearfix.

Comment: Your issue is simple... you shouldn't alternating floats.  Just `float: left;`. http://fiddle.jshell.net/zm11awhq/1/

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zm11awhq/2/

Comment: @1337 - please see my answer. To be very frank - you need to be little polite. While posting the html demo through fiddle - you could have minimized the number of line with well-structured HTML. This could have helped the community members. StakeExchange is meant much more efficient collaboration activity. I hope my answer would be helpful for you. Let me know in case you have any queries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out by myself i just added `clear: left;` on left class and `clear: right;` on right class it fix`s the season which isnt displayed correctly and rest will shows as it is.

> Thank you for everyone of your help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot acheive that look-n-feel with current structure of HTML and css. You will need to

1. Create columns - for now I have created 3 columns - you may create as many columns as you want. Further these number of columns  can be made specific to RESPONSIVE WEB BREAKPOINTS if you want to make this page responsive.
2. Associate season lists to each column
3. Apply `float:left` to each column
4. Get rid of `lef` and `right` div classes
5. Rather apply this float to columns as mentioned in # 3

Please visit the demo @ https://jsfiddle.net/zm11awhq/5/embedded/result/

If you dont want to use columns then you will need to give `min-height` to each season's div. This min-height will remain standard for all the sasons so floating will take place very properly. But this will keep lot of white space on the page.

Comment: Not quiet sure if that is what OP is what looking for

Comment: OP will need to manage these number of columns through DYNAMIC server / client side scripting. You will find exactly same look-n-feel @ www.rediff.com as well. In such cases one can not provide exact code which will work immediately after cut-copy-paste.